# PHP curl: check response for error before saving to file

Tags: php, php-curl

I have a curl script which when executed successfully returns binary content which I need to save to a file (file.wav).

But, in case of error, it returns error in json format like

```
'{ "code" : 401 , "error" : "Not Authorized" , "description" : "..." } '
```

my curl script is like

```
    $text_data = [
        'text' => $this->text
    ];
    $text_json = json_encode($text_data);

    $output_file = fopen($this->output_file_path, 'w');

    # url
    $url = $this->URL.'?voice='.$this->voice;

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $this->USERNAME.':'.$this->PASSWORD);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Accept: audio/'.$this->audio_format,
    ]);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $text_json);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $output_file);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        throw new Exception('Error with curl response: '.curl_error($ch));
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($output_file);

    $decode_result = json_decode($result);

    if (key_exists('error', $decode_result)) {
        throw new Exception($decode_result->description, $decode_result->code);
    }

    if ($result && is_file($this->output_file_path))
        return $this->output_file_path;

    throw new Exception('Error creating file');
```

This works fine when result is successful. But when there is error, the error message is also saved to `output_file` and thus that file is not readable.

**How can I check for any error before storing to file?**

> Edit 2: check response headers

```
    $header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
    $header = substr($result, 0, $header_size);
    $body = substr($result, $header_size);

    debug($header_size);      // always prints `false`
    debug($header);           // ''
    debug($body);             // '1'
```

I tried checking header response, but it is always false even on successful. Even header information is saving inside outfile file.

Comment: It'd expect a decent API server would send a proper HTTP status code on error and a correct Content-Type header every time. Is that the case?

Comment: I'm using `watson-server` to generate tts. The response is binary content on successfully and json on error. my `CURLOPT_FILE` is storing all response to the file specified.

Comment: Not sure if you're addressing to me. Have you verified the HTTP status code and headers?

Comment: check `Edit 2` I tried checking for header, but it always returns `false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a curl_getinfo() before writing to the file (and don't open it in the beginning of the code).

Example:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://www.google.com/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$c = curl_exec($ch);

if(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) != 200)
    echo "Something went wrong!";
```

Any response code not 200 (success) is considered an error, the code above will most likely not return anything as google.com is up and online ;)